# I have a black square displaying for a second whilst my video loads. How can I stop this from showing on my page? (websites.cx/video.html)?

Tags: html, video

I have a black square displaying for a second whilst my video loads. How can I stop this from showing on my page? (websites.cx/video.html)?

I'm using the html5 video attribute.
I've declared MP4 ogv mov in my htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches that could be used here-

1. Use the [*poster* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster) of the video element to set an image that will be shown in place of the video until the video loads (the specification actually states until the first frame is available).

> The poster attribute gives the address of an image file that the user agent can show while no video data is available.

Be aware that this **will** involve an extra HTTP request and as such may not be significantly advantegous in the event of a small video file and/or large placeholder image. You could mitigate the effect of the extra HTTP request by [prefetching the image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ), using a cached image, or simply ensuring you are using a well optimised image that is appropriately sized for the space you are displaying it in.

2. Set the [visibility property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) of the element to "hidden" through a class which you remove after the [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) of the video element has fired (you would need to subscribe to/listen for this event when the DOM content has loaded). I am suggesting use of the visibility property rather than display (or use of the global "hidden" attribute) as the video will still take up the defined amount of space on the page - preventing a "flash of restyled content" and re-arranging of the content around the video after it loads.

Comment: how do I listen to the load event of the video?

I have tried `<script type='text/javascript'>
$("window").load(function() {
  $("#videoclip").removeClass("preload");
});
</script>`

and setting the preload class to

`preload * {
visibility: hidden;
} `